# Get input value from parametrized method

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, richfaces, el

I'm trying to fill my input with a value from a parametrized method as I can't access to this value directly with a getter.

```
<c:forEach items="#{operationBean.tableFields}" var="tableField" varStatus="status">
    <rich:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:panelGroup>
                <h:outputText value="#{operationBean.findLabel(tableField)}"/>
                <h:inputText value="#{operationBean.filters[tableField]}" layout="block">
                    <a4j:ajax event="keyup" render="table" execute="@table"/>
                </h:inputText>
            </h:panelGroup>
        </f:facet>
        <c:choose>
            <c:when test="#{operationBean.editableColumn(tableField)}">
                <rich:inplaceInput value="#{operationBean.findOperationFieldValue(operation, tableField)}"
                        valueChangeListener="#{operationBean.changeOperationFieldValue}"
                        saveOnBlur="false">
                    <f:attribute name="tableField" value="#{tableField}"/>
                    <f:attribute name="operation" value="#{operation}"/>
                    <a4j:ajax execute="@this"/>
                </rich:inplaceInput>
            </c:when>
            <c:otherwise>
                <h:outputText value="#{operationBean.findOperationFieldValue(operation, tableField)}"/>
            </c:otherwise>
        </c:choose>
    </rich:column>
</c:forEach>
```

Obviously, JSF tries to call a setter for the `rich:inplaceInput`, cannot find it, and throws
`javax.el.PropertyNotWritableException: /faces/operations/table.xhtml @29,56 value="#{operationBean.findOperationFieldValue(operation, tableField)}": Illegal Syntax for Set Operation`

I don't need this attempted call to a setter, as the `valueChangeListener`does what I need.

I could create my own component and override UIInput.updateModel() but that would be a pain.

Comment: What exactly is your question? You apparently already understood the problem and know the answer (your model is simply wrong). This looks more like a rant and is therefore better suitable as a blog article or so.

Comment: I would life to know if there is a way to tell JSF that it is just a read only property, or that set "setter" is another method call. Do you think that's impossible ?

Comment: I can't change the operation class, as it is auto generated. And I need to access to the value with `operation.getValue(tableField)`. The only way to have a usable setter would be to create a wrapper implementing Map to use operation[tablefield]. That seems overkill.

Comment: First of all, did you have a look to [`<rich:columns />`](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/rich_columns.html) tag? It achieves basically what you want (dynamic columns). Appart from that, what you want to achieve for that output is already on the server. What you need is an intermediate view class which loads each operation field value previously and stores it as a property. Then, using JSF, just display it.

Comment: `<rich:columns />`doesn't exist anymore in richfaces 4. Extracting the data out of the object makes update in database more complex, as I am forced to merge the data.

Comment: You could try `readonly="#{not facesContext.postback or facesContext.renderResponse}`.

Comment: readOnly doesn't exist on `rich:inplaceInput`, but even on a classical field it won't fit my purpose as it disables the field.